# How to use docker with kubernetes for deployment of couchbase on windows10 home basic

Tags: docker, kubernetes, couchbase

I am trying to create kubernetes script for creating couchbase cluster on windows 10 homebasic laocally not able to do due to some linking problem, please help step by step

Comment: Pradeep, adding some more details and showing what you have tried so far will help. On Stackoverflow you won't get much help if you are asking for "tutorials" sort of!